# Is it possible with template literal types to validate that one numeric part is bigger than the next?

Tags: typescript, typescript-template-literals

I am trying to define `Record` for migration functions, that use as key the direction of the migration: `v${number}-v${number}`,

Since those are all UP migrations, they should be validated as `v${first-number}-v${first-number + 1}` and `first-number + 1` should not be more than something I defined if possible.

Does this can be done with template literals or do I have to do it at run time?

Answer (score 1):

This should do. You can also use a more general implementation of `Next` using tuples but it can get a little slow

```
type NRange<
    I extends number,
    To extends number,
    R extends number = never
> = I extends To ? R & number
    : NRange<Next<I>, To, R | I>;

type Next<N extends number> = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12][N];

type Migration<From extends number, To extends number> =
    `v${From}-v${NRange<Next<From>, To>}`


type M = Migration<2,7>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgSgQwHYHMIB4CwAoKeoCSUEAHsBEgCYDOUSArgLYBGEATgDQ75QAqA9sTIUadJq07d8cIeSq0GLdlAC8dCADd2OAHyrCskbQFQA-FBkAyMUrZS8ALliJUGGKWDoCOjn36+ZAB9CHQBuHBxQSFgPdBhDeRsJPTUAbQBGDgAmDgBmDgAWDgBWDgA2DgB2DgAODgBODnSABibM9KyAXVSYTvDsSPBoAFkASxQ2BGBR-iR0ADE2fkYE0UUJXxMPIyT2FPsoAAMNABIAb0XlgF8AWlOz+GQ0ONjLxh8-HSvDiIHsKJG+jGEymMzmOUqOhwAHpofgAHqmIA)

Comment: This will allow `v0v3` which does not respects `v${first-number}-v${first-number + 1}`

Comment: Sorry for the brain fart, this should do https://tsplay.dev/mq90rm and we're calling `Next` on `Max` to make it inclusive. Do test you utility type against edge cases